# Identity is a closed point of an affine algebraic group

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be an affine algebraic group, say over $k=\mathbb{C}$, i.e. an affine variety $(G, k[G])$ together with morphisms of affine algebraic varieties $m: G\times G\rightarrow G$ and $\text{inv}: G\rightarrow G$ and a distinguished element $e\in G$ that give $G$ the structure of a group. Then why is $\{e\}\subseteq G$ closed?

I know that any affine algebraic group is a closed subgroup of some $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ and then $e$ is the zero locus of the polynomials $x_{11}-1, \dots, x_{nn}-1, x_{12}, \dots, x_{1n}, \dots, x_{n1}, \dots, x_{n,n-1}$, hence closed. However, there has to be a way to see this directly from the definition, right? I just cannot for the life of me figure it out right now ... can someone help?

Comment: Usually if one is talking about an algebraic group $G$ over a field $k$, the identity $e$ is defined to be in $G(k)$ (or, in slightly more fancy terminology and a broader context, the identity for a relative group scheme $G\to S$ is defined to be a section of the structure map.)

Comment: Maybe adding to this: Given a $k$-variety $X$, every point $x \in X(k)$ is closed in the sense that the corresponding morphism $\operatorname{Spec}(k) \to X$ is a closed immersion (and consequently the corresponding point of the underlying topological space of X is closed).